# Equivalent(?) Order-Theoretic Definition of a Lattice

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

**Lattice Definition:** A (partially) ordered set $(A,\preceq)$ is defined to be a **lattice** when every two-element subset of $A$ has both a meet and a join (*i.e.*, a greatest lower bound and a least upper bound).

**Context:** My question relates to the manner in which the definition above focuses on *two*-element subsets of $A$. In contrast, the relation $\preceq$ is **well-founded** when *every* (non-empty) subset of $A$ has a minimal element. I understand that one advantage of focusing on two-element subsets in the order-theoretic definition of a lattice allows an easier showing of equivalency to the algebraic definition of a lattice (*e.g.*, by being able to easily define the meet binary operation as $x\wedge y:=\inf\{x,y\}$).

**Question:** Given an ordered set $(A,\preceq)$, is this ordered set a lattice under the definition given above if and only if every (non-empty) subset of $A$ has both a meet and a join?

Comment: @Luiz: did you interpret my question correctly? I am not asking if a lattice is equivalent to a well-ordered set.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, I got a little confused on the nomenclature. Let me fix that (I'll erase the old comments). Sorry about that.

Comment: No. There are lattices which which have subsets without meets and/or joins. For example, $L=[0,1)\cup(1,2]$ with the usual order is a (bounded) lattice, but the subset $[0,1)$ has no join (in $L$).

Comment: Perfect! That makes sense to me.  Thanks.

Comment: The lattices which satisfy the property that "every nonempty subset has a meet and a join" are called the **complete lattices**. Another example: $\mathbb{Q}$ is a lattice, but it is not complete. The difference between "lattices" and "complete lattices" is more-or-less the same as the difference between arbitrary ordered fields and complete ordered fields - of which there is only one up to isomorphism - $\mathbb{R}$. So in this manner, the theory of complete lattices (which is second-order) is vastly more rigid than that of lattices.